# Is there a way to permanently disable notification popups in 20.04?

Tags: notification

So the Ubuntu 20.04's notification settings changed its toggle label from "Notification Popups" to "Do Not Disturb". And in the previous versions I could permanently disable these popups with that toggle. But after upgrading to 20.04 from 19.10, I have to manually set it to Do Not Disturb on every boot. Is there a way to keep it disabled?